# Highcharts C# To JSON - Structuring Series Data

Tags: javascript, sql, json, highcharts, webforms

I am a bit stuck on this, I am trying to create a highcharts stacked column and am going round in circles attempting to get the series correct, I have pulled my data from sql server into a datatable and it is in a pivot type format (it can be changed if there is a better way), the data is in the below format as it uses the sql server pivot function:

```
name 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Bob  4 5 6 7 8 9 9 9 0 0
tim  4 5 6 7 4 3 2 5 6 3
```

The numbers along the top are the days of the month, I am wanting stack the column chart on the name and the x axis is the day of the month with the actual value being the y axis.

I have tried several permiatations of this and the latest one is to create a custom object with the day of the month as an int array. basically I am stuck as to how this can be transferred into a highcharts stacked column

the resulting JSON I believe would need to be as below:

```
{
    name: Bob
    Valie [4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,0,0]

    name: tim
    Value: [4,5,6,7,4,3,2,5,6,3]
}
```

I am ok serializing a list to a json object using JSON.net but I keep falling over when trying to produce that resulting JSON with an int array in it.

Does anybody have any best practice advice or maybe I am going about this all wrong and over complicating things I don't know. Below is my latest permiatation of an event , its just my latest one and its the result of a bit of hack and slashing in all honesty.

```
public class ChartData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Data { get; set; }
       // public int DayNumber { get; set; }

    }

protected void RenderChart()
    {

        List<int> _data = new List<int>();
        List<int> _data1 = new List<int>();
        List<string> _data2 = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow dr1 in resultsByDay.Rows)
        {
            _data.Add((int)dr1["Total"]);  //column name 
            _data1.Add((int)dr1["DayNumber"]);


            //_data.Add(new ChartData() { Data = ((int)dr1["Total"]) });
           // _data.Add(new Data() { DayNumber = ((int)dr1["DayNumber"]) });


        }
        //JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        //chartData = jss.Serialize(_data); //this make your list in jSON format like [88,99,10]
        //chartData1 = jss.Serialize(_data1);
        //chartData2 = jss.Serialize(_data2);

        JsonSerializer mySerializer = new JsonSerializer();

        chartData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data);
        chartData1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data1);
        chartData2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data2);
    }
```

My thinking is that the int needs to be changed to an int[] but a little bit unsure how to go about structing the list so that JSON.net can convert it to a lovely JSON string for highcharts to use. I have managed to get a version of this working in highcharts just not in a stacked column using the below javascript, but that's not really much good to me

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  

                 $(function () {  
                 $('#chartContainer').highcharts({
                       chart: {  
                           type: 'column' },  
                       title: {  
                       text: '' },  
                      subtitle: {  
                      text: ''},  
                      xAxis: {  
                      title: {  
                       text: "Total Output Per Day"
                                    }, 
                            labels:{
                           rotation:-25,
                           y:50 },
                     categories: <%= chartData1%>  },  
                     yAxis: {  
                            linewidth : 10,
                            gridLineWidth: 0,
                            min: 0,  
                            title: {  
                            text: 'Total'  
                      }
                    },  
                    tooltip: {  
                        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',  
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' + '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y} </b></td></tr>',  
                         footerFormat: '</table>',  
                         shared: true,  
                         useHTML: true  
                    },  
                     plotOptions: {  
                           column: {  
                           pointPadding: 0.2,  
                           borderWidth: 0 ,
                           //stacking: 'normal'
                      }
                },series: [{
                    name: "Total",
                    data: <%= chartData%>,
                dataLabels: {
                             enabled: true,
                             rotation: -90,
                                color: '#FFFFFF',
                             align: 'center',
                             x:5,
                             y:10
                             }
                      }]    
                  });  
                });
```

By the way I am working in webforms (will eventually convert to MVC :)

p.s. the data can be edited if easier into the following format:

```
Name DayNumber Total
Bob      1       5
Tim      1       10
bob      2       6
tim      2       8
bob      3       9
tim      3       5
```

Comment: I guess that you can return json in your C#, so you can use $.getJSON() in javascript and load it, istead of mixing js with c#.

Comment: Which way do you want it?  You show the database returning the data in two different formats.  You say you are working with the first format but your processing code hints at the second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear.  Your eventual plot call doesn't match what I assume you want on your plot - two series, one for Bob and one for Tim.

So let's start with with basics and get your database data into an array of Highchart series objects using JSON:

Assuming your first data structure coming back from the database:

```
name 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Bob  4 5 6 7 8 9 9 9 0 0
tim  4 5 6 7 4 3 2 5 6 3
```

This:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> allSeries = new List<Dictionary<string,object>>();
foreach (DataRow dr1 in table.Rows)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> aSeries = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    aSeries["name"] = dr1["name"];
    aSeries["data"] = new List<int>();
    int N = dr1.ItemArray.Length;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        ((List<int>)aSeries["data"]).Add((int)dr1[i]);
    }
    allSeries.Add(aSeries);
}
string jsonSeries = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allSeries);
```

in the jsonSeries string variable produces:

```
[{"name":"Bob","data":[4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,0,0]},{"name":"Tim","data":[4,5,6,7,4,3,2,5,6,3]}]
```

This for Highcharts is an array of series objects.

You could then use this in a Highcharts call as:

```
$('#chartContainer').highcharts({
    chart: {  
        type: 'column' 
    },  
    series: <%= jsonSeries %>
});
```

Which creates:

[image]

Comment: That's great, im not at my dev machine at the moment but will give it a go, you are indeed correct in that my question was a bit of a mess so thank you for trying to answer it, you know what its like when you just cant seem to get a solution straight in your head. When I look at your answer it makes perfect sense , I can then go about messing about with other charts using a similar method.

Comment: I didn't think of (or know you could) create a list of type int inside of another dictionary list, will mark as answer in due course as it looks pretty spot on.

Comment: Just tried it. thank you so much, it worked absolutely perfectly I got my stacked column chart working and it looks the business. :D

Comment: @mark Could you explain that I should go here? I do not know what to put in my case .....
foreach (DataRow dr1 in table.Rows)

Comment: @Max, I don't understand what you are asking.